# drawRect: isn't working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, ios

I want to place some "handles" on a `UIView` I have on-screen.

So, I'm creating more `UIView`s, one at each corner of the `UIView`'s frame rectangle, and I simply want to draw a circle that "fills" the rectangle that is the frame of the "handle" `UIView`.

Here's what I mean:

**How I create the "HandleView":**

```
CGPoint upperLeft = CGPointMake([[self viewToMove] frame].origin.x - 5, [[self viewToMove] frame].origin.y - 5);
HandleView *uL = [[HandleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(upperLeft.x, upperLeft.y, 10, 10)];
[self setUpperLeftHandle:uL];
[uL release];
[[self view] addSubview:[self upperLeftHandle]];
```

**drawRect: for HandleView:**

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
   // Drawing code
   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   [[UIColor orangeColor] set];
   CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, [self frame]);
}
```

What I'm getting is just a set of black rectangles where I place the HandleViews.  I'm not sure why they're black, but I can change the color by changing the `[HandleView backgroundColor]` property. I cannot, though, get anything to DRAW on this view. Calling `setNeedsDisplay` doesn't seem to make any difference.

Also, the `drawRect:` method IS being called, so there's a problem with the code there, probably not anywhere else.

It's been a while since I've messed with custom drawing, but I don't remember it being this hard.

What am I missing?

Thanks!!!

Update:

Modified code to this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // Initialization code
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 100, 100, 100, 1.0);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect);
}
```

Now, I see the circle, but only where it overlays another view. Where it's just sitting on top of the "background" UIView, I get nothing I can see. Also, even though the color is (100, 100, 100), it shows up white/light-light-gray.

What's the deal?

Comment: Uhm, I would try with CGContextSetRGBFillColor instead of [[UIColor orangeColor]set]. Also, avoid to use [self frame] inside that method: you have already the rect passed as parameter, use that or get the clip box with CGContextGetClipBoundingBox. The CGContext reference and the Quartz 2D Programming Guide cover this topic pretty good.

Comment: Yeah, the [[UIColor orangeColor] set] line was a mistake. I took that out and changed [self frame] to rect, but still no dice. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm new to asking questions here... is there a way to mark this resolved or does it just stay "open"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the following line:

CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, [self frame]);

You need to change this to the following:

CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, [self bounds]);

Origin of frame is the left-top corner location of view in the parent. So, it can be any value within the limits of the size of parent view.

So, while drawing with frame, you will be offsetting Fillellipse rect location which happens to be beyond the visible rect of the handle view.

Hence, you were not able to see anything.

Answer (score 6):

This might work:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    [[UIColor orangeColor] setFill];
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect] fill];
}
```

Comment: be aware that the rect passed in is not always the view's bounds.  So it's more correct to use [self bounds] rather than rect.

Answer (score 1):

As for the color showing up as white, it's because CGContextSetRGBFillColor() expects values from 0.0 to 1.0 for the color component values (not 0-255).  So, by passing 100, you were effectively passing 1.0, which was creating a white color.